# x[, cols] is not equivalent to x[, ..cols] and to x[, cols, with=FALSE]

Tags: r, data.table

The 1.12.2 documentation mentions `with=FALSE` is not necessary anymore to select columns dynamically. Note that `x[, cols]` is equivalent to `x[, ..cols]` and to `x[, cols, with=FALSE]`. But when I use it, I get a warning

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/data.table.pdf

```
tmp = data.table(x = numeric(0), y = numeric(0))
cols = c('x', 'y')
tmp[, cols]
```

> Error in `[.data.table`(tmp, , cols) : 
>      j (the 2nd argument inside [...]) is a single symbol but column name 'cols' is 
>      not found. Perhaps you intended DT[, ..cols]. This difference to data.frame 
>      is deliberate and explained in FAQ 1.1.

```
tmp[, ..cols]
# Empty data.table (0 rows) of 2 cols: x,y

tmp[, cols, with = FALSE]
# Empty data.table (0 rows) of 2 cols: x,y
```

I would have expected `cols` to behave similarly as per documentation. Also the variations `tmp[, ..cols]` gives object usage lint issues (which is useful for static analysis of code).

Comment: For the last two there are only warnings/messages. Try `tmp <- data.table(x = 1:5, y = 11:15)` to see.

Comment: Yes, last two work fine, but why does first not work, contrary to documentation ?

Comment: The first is interpreted as: *find a column with the name "cols" in the datatable `tmp` and give it as result*

Comment: So, is documentation incorrect ? Also, then should `with = FALSE` be used to avoid object usage linter issues ?

Comment: as I understand the documentation is correct and describes the results in your example.